# Собственная команда для загрузки fixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Существует команда `doctrine:fixture:load`, которая загрузит в мою `базу данных` определенные фейковые данные (заранее созданного fixture класса).

Хочу создать свою команду ([Console Commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#console-input)), которая будет загружать только выбранные классы с `фальшивыми данными`. В `документации` предельно все ясно, но я все-равно не могу понять, какая `логика` должна быть, что бы загружать `выбранные` фальшивые данные.

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        // название команды
        ->setName('app:create-user');
}


protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->write('Тут должна быть логика, но я не имею малейшего понятия что тут должно быть');
}
```

Я не прошу сделать задание за меня, а прошу поделиться информацией на эту тему или какими-нибудь напутствиями.

Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Да все есть уже:
`./bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/path/to/fixtures1 --fixtures=/path/to/fixtures2`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/275258)

Comment: Теперь является ответом на вопрос.